# Is there any way to track wm_messge (or wm_command) of other proccess?

Tags: c#, process, messaging, windows-process, wm-command

My computer got a virus that closes google chrome every time I open it.
I tried every related tools and malware removal I found in internet but the problem still lasts.

Now I want to create a tool(with C#.NET) that tracks other processes(or at least a chrome process that I am going to lunch with my tool) wm_message(s)(or wm_command) to see which process sends wm_message to close it and after that going to remove it.

**Is there any way to get wm_messages that a process receive ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to hear about that virus.

I would have a look at API monitor (http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor).
You should be able to listen to WM commands of specific processes using that application

Spy++ can also be used.

InterSpy (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3923/InterSpy-An-integrated-Windows-message-trace-and-f) can also trace the calls